# Implement a standard Video Player in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows Phone application with ability to play video. I have found a lot of custom video players, but I want to find out, is there a standard video player in Windows Phone and what I need to do for using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769551(v=VS.92).aspx
The MediaElement is the standard control for playing video files in WP7 apps.

Comment: and what about zune video player, can I use it in my application?

Comment: Have a look at the first link in the first sentence on that msdn page. With the MediaPlayerLauncher you can pass a video file to the standard playback software (zune) of the device. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use default media player with the help of `MediaElement` and `MediaPlayerLauncher`.
You can play local videos and urls with video.

I hope this link will help you
*http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement*